# Using ARIA trees, is it compulsory to use ul-li structure for this role?

Tags: tree, wai-aria, uiaccessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I am working on accessibility and new to the ARIA. In one of the implementation, we are using role="treeitem" but we have implemented tree using DIV structure. It's failing in JAWs. It's reading same content three times. While going through online tutorials, I found that all the sample examples are implemented using ul-li. Is div structure not supported for it?

Answer (score 0):

It is not compulsory, trees have a list like structure is all. The `treeitem` role is allowed on quite number of HTML elements. The rules for use of ARIA with HTML are defined in the [ARIA in HTML](http://w3c.github.io/html-aria/) specification

> This specification defines the web developer rules (author conformance
>   requirements) for the use of [wai-aria-1.1] attributes on [HTML51]
>   elements.

Comment: Here is the JS Fiddle. I am not sure why it's reading 3 times same content. It's in JAWs.